# Was the 1998 John Glenn Planet of the Apes prank executed?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, humor

In 1998 there was an [internet joke](http://www.cnn.com/TECH/computing/9812/08/glennape.idg/index.html) going around that proposed:

> "Pssssst. This is a secret. When John Glenn returns from space,
>   everybody dress in Ape Suits. Pass it on."

Did this Planet of the Apes joke make it to the prank phase, or was it relegated to the *wouldn't it be funny if we did this* stage?

Comment: Can you add a link / source for this prank? And is this on-topic?

Comment: @Wikis (added link) I'd like to think it's on topic. If it went beyond the proposal stage, it's a real life interaction with a scifi film franchise. If it didn't, it was a humorous interaction with a scifi film franchise.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is an interaction with Sci-Fi enough to be on-topic? I don't have a clear answer yet. (I mean, I don't have it clear in my own mind!)

Comment: The first reference; http://web.archive.org/web/20000604031029/http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~danyelf/Apes/first.html

Comment: I vote on-topic. It's sci-fi related and moderately interesting.

Comment: Sounds like a question for History.SE, not SciFi.

Comment: @Flimzy - both sites fit

Comment: @Flimzy - Also, why should they have all the fun? :-)

Comment: @Richard: Oh, as an historian, I assure you, nothing we do is even remotely fun.

Comment: This question is definitely on-topic, and pretty damn interesting to boot. I had never heard of this prank before, and really wish it had been followed up. Maybe we can get Ashton Kutcher on it next time the shuttle lands.

Comment: @DVK: Well, I know my vote doesn't officially count yet, because I don't have the requisite reputation here, but IMHO, it doesn't fit here any more than asking "Was there a Pirates of the Caribbean float in the Macy's St. Patrick's day Pared?" should fit here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. It appears that the plan wasn't executed. You can see Glenn's arrival below.

As a side note, It's not certain whether the NASA staff on the reception module tried to fool him, but none of them appear to be wearing masks as they exit.